# Twig - Output array key if array is referenced

Tags: twig

I have a series of templates which target the Twig variable `{{ file }}`, which currently outputs the file's src e.g. `"/path/to/file.jpg"`.

I want to update the contents of **file** to an array so that it stores multiple properties e.g. `{{ file.src }} {{ file.size }}`.

If I make this change then all uses of `{{ file }}` will output **Array**.

Is it possible to set Twig so that it will instead target the first property of the array? In this case `{{ file.src }}`.

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can't if your variable is a *pure* array, but you can do it with objects.

- If you want your object to be usable like an array, you need to extend [ArrayObject](http://php.net/manual/en/class.arrayobject.php) in your class.
- You can implement the magic method [__toString](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.magic.php#object.tostring) to make your object printable as a string (in your case, `$this['src']`).

Let's have an example.

1) Create the following class :

```
class File extends \ArrayObject
{
    public function __toString()
    {
        if (isset($this['src']))
        {
            return $this['src'];
        }
    }
}
```

2) In a controller, initialize your object.

```
$file = new File();
$file['src'] = 'my_file.png';
$file['size'] = 42;
```

3) In your twig file, try it :

```
{{ file }}<br/>
{{ file.src }}<br/>
{{ file.size }}<br/>
```

4) Enjoy

[image]